# Batch-render banners with differing image and text

Tags: flash, rendering, actionscript-2, batch-processing

For a current project I need to create 25 versions of 5 different banner sizes. By version, I mean having slightly different content, namely: a different image and different text somewhere in the banner.

Let's, for this question, suppose I'll make sure somehow that said images and texts will all fit fine in the design for that particular size, so that I could create some sort of template per size, with some sort of placeholders for them. What is an efficient method, if any, to automate the rendering of these differing versions per size? Is it possible?

**Some requirements:**

- Actionscript 2
- The rendered swf should only contain the image meant for that swf (so, not all possible images).
- Idem for the text, although a little less important as you can imagine.

**Tools I'm most comfortable working with:**

- Adobe Flash IDE CS3
- Writing actionscript 2 classes files primarily meant for the Flash IDE, not Flex.

Although I might consider using Flex, but preferably not.

So, concluding, I'm looking for something like this:

- For each size, I'll create some data-file with locations of 25 images and their accompanying texts.
- Have some automated process read this data-file and merge each 'record' with some sort of Flash template, thereby automatically rendering the 25 different versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I want to help bring 125 banners to the world, hehe, but kidding aside, you could take a look at JSFL, the macro scripting language for the Flash IDE:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=Part7_Extending_Flash_1.html

Comment: Does it help if I say the banners are for somewhat of a good cause? ;-) But JSFL; good suggestion, that might just be what I'm looking for! I even used it once or twice I think, but forgot all about it. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, that feels a lot better!